# How to create an ssl certificate programatically with php?

Tags: php, ssl, openssl

I am looking for a way to create an ssl certificate from php.

I have the openssl.cnf and the private key on disk and accessible.

One option was to execute a shell script, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it directly from php.

Comment: If your version of php is compiled with openssl included, you can use those functions.. http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[openssl_csr_new](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-csr-new.php)

Note: as a requirement you do have to have openssl.cnf

Comment: This is a really helpful answer!